# indexoutofboundsexception by sending pictures over Socket

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to make a little programm that makes a live-stream for Desktop.
It should be so that you send pictures to an echo-server and he response it to the clients.
There you get be draw the Images. Side by Side. And so it is like a movie(or something like that).
But I always get an indexoutofboundsexception. Where is the error or how can I improve my program.

The ImageIO.write lines thows the Error

//Client Main

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Frame frm = new Frame();

    Frame.Client client;

    frm.setLayout(null);
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(Frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.setResizable(false);
    frm.setSize(1600,900);
    frm.setVisible(true);



}
```

}

// get and send the Desktopimage

public class desktopCapture {

```
Robot robo;
BufferedImage screenImage;
Rectangle bounding;

public desktopCapture() {
    try {
        bounding = new Rectangle(0,0,1600,900);
        robo = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void sendScreenCapture(Socket client) {
    screenImage = robo.createScreenCapture(bounding);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(screenImage, "png", client.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

}

// in Frame two function for actionListener Objects, so I can say who streams his Desktop and which get only the Images to.
public void readImage() {
            while(true) {

```
            try {
                while((screenImage = ImageIO.read(in)) != null){

                    repaintScreen();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
```

public void sendImage() {

```
        try {
            while(true){
            dC.sendScreenCapture(client);
            System.out.println("read1");
            while((screenImage = ImageIO.read(in)) != null){
            System.out.println("read2");
            ImageIO.write(screenImage, "png", new File("image1.png"));

            Thread.sleep(250);
            }
            repaintScreen();
            screenImage = null;

            }   
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

     }
    }

}
```

//Thread for a Client

public class handler implements Runnable {

```
Socket client;
OutputStream out;
InputStream in; 
PrintWriter writer;
BufferedImage image;

public handler(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        in = client.getInputStream();       
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("write1");
        while((image = ImageIO.read(in)) != null){
            System.out.println("write2");
    for(int i = 1;i <= Server.connectionArray.size();i++){
        Socket TEMP_SOCK = (Socket)Server.connectionArray.get(i-1);
     out = TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream();
     writer = new PrintWriter(out);

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("write3");
        }
      image = null;
     }
    }

    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

}

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to determine why the code tries to access an index which is out of range?

Comment: oh .. Sorry .. The ImageIO.write lines thows it

Comment: Very hard to believe. Post the stack trace.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `for` loop to:

```
int count = Server.connectionArray.size()
int index  = count - 1; 
for(int i = 0;i < count; i++){
        Socket TEMP_SOCK = (Socket)Server.connectionArray.get(index);
        out = TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(out);

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("write3");
  }
```

Comment: when I use this I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException by                     Socket TEMP_SOCK = (Socket)Server.connectionArray.get(i);

Comment: This way works and now is indexoutofboundsexception only by desktopCapture left. By my Server the problem is solved I think so.  but the client have now the problem by the function desktopCapture. At imageIO.write();